# Is it safe to use length instead of ==""?

Tags: javascript

Is it safe to use `length` property instead of `==""` for empty string validation?

Is it valid on all bool operators?

It might be a very simple question and I am pretty sure that the answer is a yes/yes, but I am using it a lot recently and I am a bit worried about any possible pitfall.

For completeness, here is a simple example

```
var valid = name.length && (foo.length||bar.length);
```

Comment: You could use `var valid = name` because empty string is a falsy value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always safe to use `.length` IF you know for sure that you have something in the variable that can have properties (like a string).

But, if the variable might be `undefined` or `null`, then `.length` will not be valid and will not do what you want and `name === ""` would be safer.

Many Javascript developers simply do:

```
if (name) {
    // 
}
```

This checks for any truthy value in `name`.  So, the `if` will not be satisfied if `name` is `undefined`, `null` or even an empty string `""` and, in some cases, protects your code a bit more than what you were doing.

---

Or, in your example, you could perhaps just do:

```
var valid = name && (foo || bar);
```

This will require `name` and either `foo` or `bar` to be truthy.  This won't protect against `name`, `foo` or `bar` being some type of data without a `.length` property like your original code would, but it would do a better job of protecting against any of these variables being `undefined` or `null`.

Remember that an empty string `""` is a falsey value so you can use that to your advantage in boolean comparisons.